# Como criar um array preenchido com os valores de 0 a n em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso criar um array que seja preenchido com os valores de 0 a `n`, como se utilizasse a função `range(n)`, do Python3, mas utilizando os recursos do Javascript.

Pensei em criar uma função:

```
function generateRange(n){
    let range = new Array(n);

    range.forEach((x, index) => {
      x = index+1;
    })

    return range;
}
```

Mas achei essa forma trabalhosa demais, e, talvez, desnecessária. Existe uma forma mais simples de tratar esses dados e gerar o mesmo resultado?

Comment: Arthur, esse seu método na minha opinião, está bem clean, facil de entender, por mais q eu faça um codigo diferente pra vc, é possível q vc n ache ele melhor q o seu, entao sua pergunta é baseada em opinião.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mais simples não quer dizer necessariamente mais claro, o seu método me parece bom, mas se quiser algo mais simples, pode usar o [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), que basicamente retornar um array e executa um map dentro, o que permite ir incrementando os valores:

```js
function generateRange(n){
   return Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => i + 1);
}

console.log(generateRange(10));
```

Se quisesses valores iguais, seria mais simples ainda, bastando usar [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
function generateRange(totalElementos, valor){
       return Array(totalElementos).fill(valor);
    }

console.log(generateRange(10, 5));
```

Ainda há uma forma mais simples, usando [Array.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys), quer retorna a chave do índice, ou seja, uma sequencia numérica, talvez o mais simples para o que seu caso:

```js
function generateRange(totalElementos){
    return Array.from(Array(totalElementos).keys());
    }

console.log(generateRange(10));
```

Answer (score 7):

Não tem milagre, a única coisa é que eu acho uma bobagem usar `forEach()`, pegou moda as pessoas fazerem isto mas tem zero necessidade, é um complicador, costuma deixar mais longo e certamente mais lento sem dar legibilidade extra alguma, pelo contrário, é comum as pessoas não entenderem as consequências de fazer isto, além de impedir certas construções, é só moda. Eu faria assim:

```js
function generateRange(n) {
    let range = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) range[i] = i + 1;
    return range;
}
console.log(generateRange(5));
```

Certamente tem função que pode reduzir um pouco, se puder usar algo pronto e versões modernas do JS pode usar alternativas, por exemplo:

```js
console.log(Array.from({length: 5}, (v, k) => k + 1));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Fill.js).

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript não possui nenhuma maneira pronta de se gerar um array preenchido em uma única linha. Algo que eu gostaria que fosse padrão no JavaScript seria uma função `range` para gerar um iterador.

Se você quiser implementar uma você mesmo, poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
function* range(inicio, fim, incremento = 1) {
    if (fim === undefined) {
        [inicio, fim] = [0, inicio];
    }

    if (fim > inicio) {
        if (incremento < 0) incremento *= -1;
        for (var i = inicio; i < fim; i += incremento) {
            yield i;
        }
    } else {
        if (incremento > 0) incremento *= -1;
        for (var i = inicio; i > fim; i += incremento) {
            yield i;
        }
    }
}

// Array de 0 a 5
var arr1 = Array.from(range(5));
console.log(arr1);

// Também funciona com o operador rest 
var arr2 = [...range(5)];
console.log(arr2);

// Array de 5 a 10
var arr3 = [...range(5, 10)];
console.log(arr3);

// Array de 0 a 10 incrementando de 2 em 2
var arr4 = [...range(0, 10, 2)];
console.log(arr4);

// Array de 10 a 0 decrementando de 2 em 2
var arr5 = [...range(10, 0, -2)];
console.log(arr5);

// Também funciona como iterador
for (var i of range(3)) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso usando apenas uma linha, usando os métodos `keys()` e `from()` do `ES6`, da seguinte maneira:

```js
let array = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
console.log(array);
```

Ou usando o`spread operator`, fica menor ainda:

```js
let array = [...Array(10).keys()];
console.log(array);
```

Dessa forma, o array sempre começa do zero, para começar de outro numero a sua escolha, terá que passar um função de mapping:

```js
let array = Array.from(Array(10), (e, i) => i + 1); // basta trocar o 1, pelo número que voce quer que comece o array
console.log(array);
```